# Absolute VS Relative URLs in a JSP/JavaScript web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, web-applications

How do you handle **URLs in Javascript files in your Java web applications**, e.g. when doing AJAX requests?

Do you always use the **absolute URL** for the AJAX call? (including the web application context) - what if the application context changes?

Or do you use **relative URLs**? This is difficult because a JSP file could be loaded via multiple different URL mappings in the application.

To make it clearer:

Say I got a java application myapp.war that is running under http://www.example.com/myapp/

In a Javascript file I want to make an AJAX call to /getData.json - I could do this via absolute URL:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/myapp/getData.json",
  cache: false
}).done(function(data) {
  ... 
});
```

this works only as long as I do not rename the app

or via a relative URL

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getData.json",
  cache: false
}).done(function(data) {
  ... 
});
```

but the relative URL only works if the current page is in the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute is preferred; consider how often you're going to change your application name vs. the times you'll mess with the file structure *(hint: almost never vs. not so rarely, accordingly)*.

Using absolute paths is also advised by negation; if you're going with *relative paths*, changing file locations is the least of your problems - think about what happens when you start ***refactoring your code*** (which is the quite common): methods, possibly containing brittle URL references, get extracted to utility classes all the time, and such classes will probably lay in other files.

The bottom line is that *relative paths* will effectively render your code **rigid** while *absolute paths* will allow for more **flexibility**.